# same code different result when building in XCode 5.1.1 vs. XCode 6.1.1

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller, user-experience, xcode6.1

I have a working app on the app store that was written and built on XCode 5.1 moving to XCode 6.1 (with XCode 6.0 there were no problems) I'm encountering wired UX behaviors.

I have created a popover that appears above a given button and it looks like this:
[image]

And the code to achieve that is the following:

```
+(UIPopoverController*)openPopover:(UIViewController*)p_popoverView size:(CGSize)p_popoverSize aboveButton:(UIButton*)p_button inTarget:(id)p_target
{
    UIPopoverController* popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:p_popoverView];
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:p_popoverSize];
    [popover setDelegate:p_target];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:p_button.bounds
                             inView:p_button
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
                           animated:YES];
    return popover;
}
```

**Same code** compiled in xcode 6.1 result in the following UX:

[image]

the entire screen is covered, the button is not showing nor the popover frame, although width from checkbox to image seem the same as the original.

this is just one of many differences caused by compiling the same project with XCode 6.1

1. did anyone encounter the same problems?
2. how can I fix this?
3. heads up what on other "surprises" or things to look for.

Comment: You say "crashes with the following exception" but I don't see any crash or exception information.

Comment: @PhillipMills thanks for pointing that out. I've started writing the question when i had a crash & an exception, which i resolved. Now I only need to figure out why the popover takes over the entire screen